# Pushing different data to multiple objects results in same data being pushed to all objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a large "master object" (objMaster) containing a lot of data.

I have 3 separate JSON objects (I know, not "technically" objects) for 3 categories that will hold some data calculated from values in objMaster. Let's call them:
    objCategory1, objCategory2, objCategory3

i'm attempting to push data into these categorized objects at a designated index. The issue is, if I push separate data to each categorized object, it's pushing all the data to each object.

```
$(objMaster).each(function(j,v){    
   var myCat1data = objMaster[j].Cat1Completed / objMaster[j].Cat1Total ;
   var myCat2data = objMaster[j].Cat2Completed / objMaster[j].Cat2Total ;
   var myCat3data = objMaster[j].Cat3Completed / objMaster[j].Cat3Total ;

   objCategory1[j].data.push(myCat1data);       
   objCategory2[j].data.push(myCat2data);
   objCategory3[j].data.push(myCat3data);       
});
```

results in objCategory1[j].data getting values for myCat1data, myCat2data, and myCat3data not just the values for myCat1data. The same for objCategory2[j].data and objCategory3[j].data.

If I comment out the pushes to objCategory2 & objCategory3 then objCategory1[j].data only gets the myCat1data values.

```
$(objMaster).each(function(j,v){    
   var myCat1data = objMaster[j].Cat1Completed / objMaster[j].Cat1Total ;
   var myCat2data = objMaster[j].Cat2Completed / objMaster[j].Cat2Total ;
   var myCat3data = objMaster[j].Cat3Completed / objMaster[j].Cat3Total ;

   objCategory1[j].data.push(myCat1data);       
   // objCategory2[j].data.push(myCat2data);
   // objCategory3[j].data.push(myCat3data);        
});
```

Any ideas what's going on here?

UPDATE:
I'm initializing the category arrays using a similar iteration

```
var objCategory1= [];
var objCategory2= [];
var objCategory3= [];

// create category dataset shells
$(objMaster).each(function(j,v){    

  var myDataSet = {
   label: mycategory,
   data: []
 }; 

 // push dataset shell to associated chart data objects
 objCategory1.push(myDataSet);
 objCategory2.push(myDataSet);
 objCategory3.push(myDataSet);
});
```

Comment: How do the `.data` properties get initialized? For that matter how do the `objCategory` arrays get initialized?

Comment: Also there's no such thing as a JSON object; they're JavaScript objects.

Comment: Can you show the data  initialization? Is it array?

Comment: You're pushing the exact same "data set" object into all three arrays.  The `.push()` operation does not make a copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of initializing like this

```
var objCategory1= [];
var objCategory2= [];
var objCategory3= [];

// create category dataset shells
$(objMaster).each(function(j,v){    

  var myDataSet = {
   label: mycategory,
   data: []
 }; 

 // push dataset shell to associated chart data objects
 objCategory1.push(myDataSet);
 objCategory2.push(myDataSet);
 objCategory3.push(myDataSet);
});
```

can you try this

```
var objCategory1= [];
var objCategory2= [];
var objCategory3= [];

// create category dataset shells
$(objMaster).each(function(j,v){    
 objCategory1.push({ label: mycategoy, data: [] });
 objCategory2.push({ label: mycategoy, data: [] });
 objCategory3.push({ label: mycategoy, data: [] });
});
```

this will initailize the objCategoryies with different data arrays

Answer (score 0):

you're pushing a reference to the same object here into all 3 'objCategoryX' arrays:

```
var myDataSet = {
   label: mycategory,
   data: []
 };     

 objCategory1.push(myDataSet);
 objCategory2.push(myDataSet);
 objCategory3.push(myDataSet);
```

instead, you need to create new objects for every use:

```
objCategory1.push({
       label: mycategory,
       data: []
     });
objCategory2.push({
       label: mycategory,
       data: []
     });
objCategory3.push({
       label: mycategory,
       data: []
     });
```